# Jenkins - Git Publisher - Error The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm using the Git Publisher feature of Git Plugin of Jenkins to push my build to another repository, but the following error appears:

"ERROR: Failed to push branch master to github
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe push https://github.com/rodolfoprr/teste2.git HEAD:master" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com/rodolfoprr/teste2.git'"

My configuration:

**Source Code Management**

Git

- Repositories:

Repository URL: git//github.com/rodolfoprr/teste.git

Credentials: none

Repository URL: https://github.com/rodolfoprr/teste2.git

Credentials: rodolfoprr/****** (github)

Name: github

**Git Publisher**

Push Only If Build Succeeds checked

- Branches:

Branch to push: master

Target remote name: github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem:

In the first build, I added a "build step" -> "execute shell":

git checkout master

The following builds, I deleted this step.

This link helped me: http://thingsyoudidntknowaboutjenkins.tumblr.com/post/23596855946/git-plugin-part-3